# What was in the box?

Tags: rivers-of-london

As far as I understand, the reason for the magical occurrences in "Winter's Gifts" was

> some thing in a "box" that was buried at the site where the Marsh expedition had died.
>  During the events of the book some guy had dug the box out, and later Walker had got its hands on it. And the box was ice-cold.

But: what was actually in that box? Was that ever explained?

Comment: Ice creams, I expect.

Comment: @Valorum: not what I meant :-)